# Pubsub Subscription error for TIMESTAMP data type: Incompatible schema type

Tags: google-bigquery, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I was working on the new bigquery subscription for pubsub and came across an error when trying to create the subscription:

> Incompatible schema type for field 'timestamp': field is STRING in the topic schema, but TIMESTAMP in the BigQuery table schema.

However, in the [pubsub documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/bigquery#schema_compatibility) there is this statement:

> When the type in the topic schema is a string and the type in the BigQuery table is TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE, or TIME, then any value for this field in a Pub/Sub message must adhere to the format specified for the BigQuery data type.

As far as I understand, that means it's possible to insert into a TIMESTAMP column in bigquery as long as the string complies with [canonical format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#canonical_format_for_timestamp_literals) defined for TIMESTAMP data type.
Am I missing something?

---

For more info, this is the conflicting part of bigquery and pubsub topic schema that I use:

- Bigquery schema

  ```
  [ 
    {
      "description": "The exact time when this request is being sent. Set as UTC",
      "mode": "REQUIRED",
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "TIMESTAMP"
    }
  ]
  ```
- Pubsub topic schema

  ```
  syntax = "proto2";

  message ExampleMessage {
    required string timestamp = 10;
  }
  ```

*Update: removed space in message name for pubsub topic*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue isn't with the field `timestamp` itself, but with the name of the message type, `Example Message`. The message type name has a space, which should not be permitted. At this time, Pub/Sub's Protocol Buffer schema validation is more permissive than the standard parser and does not catch errors like this. If you change the name to `ExampleMessage`, it should work.

A fix for this issue has already been prepared. You can follow the progress of the fix in the [public bug on issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245980876).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, it wasn't actually separated with space, it was mistyped. The actual message that triggers the error was named with pascal case/upper camel case without space

Comment: What properties are you setting on the subscription? You selected "use topic schema," I take it.

Comment: Yes, sure. I checked on the "use topic schema" option.

Comment: for more detail, both "write metadata" and "drop unknown fields" options were off